# How to get customizer to refresh when using radio buttons control

Tags: theme-customizer

I have set up a set of radio buttons in the customizer to specify one of several different color schemes (aka style sheets) in my theme. When I select a new color for the theme the preview of the theme does not changes. But in another part of the customizer I have a text box. After selecting a color scheme if I go to the text box control and modify it and remove the text cursor, probably causing a change event, then the theme updates and shows the selected color scheme. How can I cause the preview to update when I change the color through the control with the radio buttons?

```
$wp_customize->add_section('cb_colors_schemes', array(
    'title' => __('Color Schemes', 'wpforge'),
    'description' => __('Change the color scheme of your theme.', 'wpforge'),
    'priority' => 70,
 ));         

$wp_customize->add_setting('cb_color_scheme', array(
    'default' => 'blue',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
    'capability' => 'manage_options',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'wpforge_sanitize_cs_selection',
    'priority' => 4,        
));

$wp_customize->add_control('cb_color_scheme', array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'label' => 'Color Scheme:',
    'section' => 'cb_colors_schemes',
    'choices' => array(
        'black' => 'Black',
        'blue' => 'Blue',
        'brown' => 'Brown',
        'gray-red' => 'Gray-Red',
        'green' => 'Green',
        'orange' => 'Orange',
        'purple' => 'Purple',
        'red' => 'Red',
        'taupe' => 'Taupe',
        'turqoise' => 'Turqoise',
        ),
    )
);

function wpforge_sanitize_cs_selection( $input ) {
    $valid = array(
        'black' => 'Black',
        'blue' => 'Blue',
        'brown' => 'Brown',
        'gray-red' => 'Gray-Red',
        'green' => 'Green',
        'orange' => 'Orange',
        'red' => 'Red',
        'purple' => 'Purple',
        'taupe' => 'Taupe',
        'turqoise' => 'Turqoise'
     );

     if ( array_key_exists( $input, $valid ) ) {
        return $input;
     } else {
        return '';
     }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
( function( $ ) {

// Header

    wp.customize('blogname', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('.site-title a').html(to);
    });
});
    wp.customize('blogdescription', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('.site-description').html(to);
    });
});
    wp.customize('hide_headtxt', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        if( to == '' ) {
            $('.site-title, .site-description').css('display', 'none');
        }
        else if( to == 1 ) {
            $('.site-title, .site-description').css('display', 'block');
        };
    });
});
// Footer
    wp.customize('wpforge_footer_text', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('.site-info').html(to);
    });
}); 
// Background
    wp.customize('wpforge_background_color', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('body').css('background-color', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('body').css('background-color', '');
        }
        });
    });
    wp.customize('wpforge_background_img', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("'+to+'")');
        if( to == '' ){
            $('body').css('background-image', '');
        }
        });
    });
    wp.customize('wpforge_background_repeat', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('body').css('background-repeat', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('body').css('background-repeat', '');
        }
       });
    });
    wp.customize('wpforge_background_size', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('body').css('background-size', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('body').css('background-size', '');
        }
        });
    }); 
    wp.customize('wpforge_background_position', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('body').css('background-position', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('body').css('background-position', '');
        }
        });
    });
    wp.customize('wpforge_background_attachment', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('body').css('background-attachment', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('body').css('background-attachment', '');
        }
    });
   });  
   // Fonts & Colors
    wp.customize('wpforge_title_color', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').css('color', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').css('color', '');
        }
        });
    });
    wp.customize('wpforge_text_color', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('body').css('color', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('body').css('color', '');
        }
        });
    });
    wp.customize('wpforge_link_color', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('a').css('color', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('a').css('color', '');
        }
        });
    }); 
    wp.customize('wpforge_hover_color', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
        $('a:hover').css('color', to);
        if( to == '' ){
            $('a:hover').css('color', '');
        }
        });
    }); 

 } )( jQuery );
```

Comment: Can you post your jS?

Comment: Ah, good idea. Since I did not write this I did not know there was some JavaScript related to this code. I added the JS code.

Comment: At first glance I wonder if this isn't working because there doesn't seem to be jS for "cb_color_scheme", and also, is that input actually properly assigned to a section? Sadly I don't have much time to help, but that's where I'd start!

Comment: Yes, what javascript needs to be added to request refresh after cb_color_scheme change?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple. Change the transport property to refresh:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('cb_color_scheme', array(
  'default' => 'blue',
  'type' => 'theme_mod',
  'transport' => 'refresh', 
  'capability' => 'manage_options',
  'sanitize_callback' => 'wpforge_sanitize_cs_selection',
  'priority' => 4,      
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the default is refresh, so there is no need to have

```
'transport' => 'refresh',
```